# Add property to inherited ListBox and override a method to change it

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, listbox

I'm trying to create a class that inherits from **ListBox** and adding the property **PreviousSelectedIndex** to it. So far all good.

Next, I'm trying to set that property before the **SelectedIndex** is changed.

The problem is that I cannot find the method on which the property **SelectedIndex** is changed so I can capture it. I always can change it manually on the object itself but that is only a workaround. Here is what I got:

```
public class MyListBox : System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
{
    public int PreviousSelectedIndex { get; set; }

    public MyListBox() : base()
    {
        this.PreviousSelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.PreviousSelectedIndex = base.SelectedIndex;
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

When I'm trying:

```
MessageBox.Show(
            "Previous Index = " + listBox4.PreviousSelectedIndex +
            "\nCurrent Index = " + listBox4.SelectedIndex
            );
```

I always get the same value.

Also I tried it with **OnMouseDown()** and **OnSelectedIndexChanged()** with no luck.

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Winform, you could do:

```
public class MyListBox : System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
{
    private int _selectedIndex = -1;
    public int PreviousSelectedIndex { get; set; }

    public MyListBox() : base()
    {
        this.PreviousSelectedIndex = -1;
        this.SelectedIndexChanged += OnSelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    private void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        PreviousSelectedIndex = _selectedIndex;
        _selectedIndex = this.SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

IF you want to change to WPF, you can get the previous item from the SelectedChanged event of the ListBox

```
public MyListBox() : base()
{
    this.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    this.PreviousSelectedIndex = -1;
}

private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.RemovedItems.Count == 0)
    {
        this.PreviousSelectedIndex = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        this.PreviousSelectedIndex = this.Items.IndexOf(e.RemovedItems[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 3 errors:
Error 1: 'FinalProject.MyListBox' does not contain a definition for 'SelectionChanged' and no extension method 'SelectionChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'FinalProject.MyListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


Error 2: The type or namespace name 'SelectionChangedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


Error 3: 'FinalProject.MyListBox' does not contain a definition for 'IndexOf' and no extension method 'IndexOf' accepting a first argument of type 'FinalProject.MyListBox'...

Comment: Can't to that at the current stage of the project.

Comment: Sorry to hear, maybe next project